# Facebook XMPP Chat knowing when friend types

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, xmpp

Is there a way to know through Facebook's XMPP Chat if a friend that is writing a message to me started typing ? (so I can display the 'X is typing' message we see in chat clients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook follows [XEP-0085: Chat State Notifications](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html), so look for something like this in incoming messages:

```
<composing xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
```